# Alignment of multlined equations in algorithm

Tags: equations, algorithms, algorithmicx, multline, algpseudocode

I would like to align the `multline` equation within `algorithm` environment such that it fits the current block (aligned with the beginning of the line `# Solve the equation:` in the example bellow):

[image]

The minimal version of the code:

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[ruled,norelsize]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithmicx}

\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State \(\#\) #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!t]
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \begin{algorithmic}
      \Statex
      \For{$i = 1, ..., n$}
        \LineComment{Solve the equation:}
        \begin{equation}
        \begin{multlined}[c]
          a = 222222222 + 222222222222222 + 222222 +  \\
          %
          + 222222222222222222
        \end{multlined}
        \end{equation}
      \EndFor        \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:** showing that the suggested solution does not work in nested loops:

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,nccmath}

\usepackage[ruled,norelsize]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithmicx}

\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State \(\#\) #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!t]
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \begin{algorithmic}
      \While{not converged}
        dnwjkfn
        \Statex
        \For{$i = 1, ..., n$}
          \LineComment{Solve the equation:}
          \State\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
          \begin{fleqn}[\dimexpr\leftmargini-\labelsep]
          \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
          \begin{equation}
              \begin{multlined}[c]
                a = 222222222 + 222222222222222 + 222222 \\
                  + 222222222222222222
              \end{multlined}
          \end{equation}
          \end{fleqn}%
        \EndFor
      \EndWhile
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,nccmath}

\usepackage[ruled,norelsize]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithmicx}

\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State \(\#\) #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!t]
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \begin{algorithmic}
      \Statex
      \For{$i = 1, ..., n$}
        \LineComment{Solve the equation:}
        \State\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
        \begin{fleqn}[\dimexpr\leftmargini-\labelsep]
        \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
        \begin{equation}
            \begin{multlined}[c]
              a = 222222222 + 222222222222222 + 222222 \\
                + 222222222222222222
            \end{multlined}
        \end{equation}
        \end{fleqn}%
      \EndFor \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: For the case of nested environment, you can increase the number og `\leftmargin--\labelsep` in the optional argument of the `fleqn` environment:

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,nccmath}

\usepackage[ruled,norelsize]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithmicx}

\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State \(\#\) #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!t]
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \begin{algorithmic}
      \While{not converged}
        dnwjkfn
        \Statex
        \For{$i = 1, ..., n$}
          \LineComment{Solve the equation:}
          \State\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
          \begin{fleqn}[\dimexpr(\leftmargini-\labelsep)*2]
          \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
 \begin{equation}
                \begin{multlined}[c]
                a = 222222222 + 222222222222222 + {}\\
                  + 222222 +222222222222222222
              \end{multlined}
          \end{equation}
          \end{fleqn}%
        \EndFor
      \EndWhile
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what exactly is going on here? It works for this particular example, but if the equation is in a nested loop, this solution does the alignment for the outer loop and not the inner loop.

Comment: I didn't test the case of nested loops, and I don't think this workaround can work. The `fleqn` environment, from `nccmath` changes locally the alignment of equations on the left margin (like the `fleqn` option of  `amsmath` does globally), and its optional argument  specifies the value of this left margin (0pt by default). As the different line indentations in `algorithmic` correspond to list indentations, I tested with parameters from first level lists.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make it independent on levels?

Comment: I've just tested on an example, and I have no problem. Could you post (alink to) an example? The `fleqn` must be the outer environment, since is a switch, somewhat like `subequations`.

Comment: Could you please take a look? I updated the question.

Comment: Another question is why do you use `nccmath`? Is it possible to do everything with `mathtools`? From the documentation it provides `fleqn` environment.

Comment: I use  `nccmath` (which is just another extension of `amsmath`, much less powerful than `mathtools`) because it's this extension which  defines the `fleqn` environment (also I sometimes use it because of its `medsize` environment  and related commands).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56045/discussion-between-desa-and-bernard).

Comment: @desa: I've added a solution for your new code. Had to split differently the `multlined`, so the equation  number does not go under the equation.